# Formatting String to 1 Decimal Place, without rounding up/down

Tags: c#, string

I want a function that is passed an integer, and if that integer is over a certain value (1000 in my current case) I want to perform some division on it so I can ultimately return an abbreviation of the original integer.

For example:

```
1000 = 1
1001 = 1
1099 = 1
1100 = 1.1
1199 = 1.1
1200 = 1.2
10000 = 10
10099 = 10
10100 = 10.1
```

It's the division and rounding side of things that has been causing me problems.

What would be the most suitable method to give me the results above?

Comment: What you're looking for is "truncation", which is a form of rounding called "rounding toward 0".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
int dividedBy100 = x / 100; // Deliberately an integer division
decimal dividedBy1000 = dividedBy100 / 10m; // Decimal division
string result = dividedBy1000.ToString();
```

I would advise using `decimal` here rather than `float` or `double`, as you fundamentally want decimal division by 10.

Comment: @Gabe: It would do exactly the same - the integer truncation would round towards zero.

Answer (score 0):

An abbreviation is by definition rounded.

If you are looking for more precision why not use Double instead of Integer?

Answer (score 0):

if t is the original number, then

```
int a=t/100

float b=a/10
```

b should contain your answer

Some more code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string s;
                s = Console.ReadLine();
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(s);
                a = a / 100;
                float b = a / (float)10.0;
                Console.WriteLine(b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion

```
double function(int number)
{
    if (number >= 1000)
    {
       return (((double)number) / 1000);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
int MyNumber = 10100;

string MyString = ((int) MyNumber/1000).ToString() + (( MyNumber % 1000) > 99 ? "." + (((int)( MyNumber / 100 )) % 10).ToString() : "");
```

Comment: This prints `10.0` for `10000` when the OP says he wants `10` (no decimal point).

Answer (score 0):

Your examples seem to imply that you only want one decimal place of precision, so how about something like this:

1. Divide by 100
2. Cast to double (or float)
3. Divide by 10

The first division will truncate any trailing numbers less than 100 (the equivalent of a 100-base floor function), then casting to double and dividing by 10 will give you the single decimal place of precision you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use modular (remainder) mathematics to do this. You don't need to involve the FPU (Floating Point Unit).

```
static string RoundAndToString(int value, int denominator)
{
    var remainder = value % denominator;
    value = (value - remainder) / denominator;
    if (remainder == 0)
        return value.ToString();
    remainder = (remainder * 10) / denominator;
    return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator, remainder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to truncate the number, it makes sense to convert it to a string, remove the last two characters from the string, then divide by 10 to get the corresponding number.

Here is the algorithm in Ruby. (I don't have C# handy)

```
a = 1000 #sample number
 -> 1000

b = a.to_s[0..-3] #a converted to a string, then taking all characters except the last two.
 -> "10"

c = b.to_i / 10.0 # converts to float in correct power
 -> 1.0
```

You then display "c" in whatever format you want using sprintf (or the C# equivalent using FormatNumber).